# Why does sudo ask for a password?

Tags: sudo

```
USER@notebook:~/foo/notebook$ sudo /usr/bin/mplayer /home/USER/foo/notebook/something.mp3
[sudo] password for USER: 
USER@notebook:~/foo/notebook$ 

USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mplayer /home/USER/foo/notebook/something.mp3
```

**Question:** sudo didn't ask for a password. Now it asks.. Why? The sudo package and the sudoers file wasn't updated, the USER's pwd isn't expired.

Playing an mp3 via ssh and sudo is needed because it doesn't play the sound 
without it, strange..

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Well if it wasn't happenning before but now it happens, then something changed. Was there an update, even if it didn't touch the sudo binary or sudoers file?

Comment: yepp, mplayer was removed :D found the problem :D lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `mplayer` was removed from the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudoers` file is sensitive to the order of entries within it. The `NOPASSWD` entry must come after any other entries matching your user to take precedence.

The rule is, "last match wins."